# Webdriver: Unable to select combox using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have combox when expanded shows the country code mobile number formats. I'm tyring to automate this combo box. I tried with Xpath, ID locators but not able to select the combo box. Please let me know where am failing

```html
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-mobile1-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-mobile1-container"><span class="">Select</span></span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
```

Comment: I tried selecting the ID of this dropbox but no luck

Comment: What do you mean by `not able to select the combo box`?? is there any exception?? also share your tried code??

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: `public void enter_Personal_Details() throws Throwable {
      try {
       
       Thread.sleep(30000);
       
       Select select = new Select( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-mobile1-container'])")));
      
      select.selectByVisibleText("056");
      }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use method :

```
public void isChooseFromCombo(String text){                         
String yourXpath="//*[contains(text),'"text"')]"; 
List<WebElement> element =
getWebElement.findElement(By.xpath(yourXpath));             
  for(WebElement we : element){
   if(we.getText.contains(text)){
       we.click
  }
}
```

Comment: OK 007777ewq let me try and will get back in case of any issues.

Comment: Any other way without using method ?

Comment: No its not working am seeing same issue the option is not selected from combo box

Comment: write your code please ,i think you need check xpath

Comment: also see this link :      https://github.com/ggasoftware/gga-selenium-framework/blob/master/gga-selenium-framework-core/src/main/java/com/ggasoftware/uitest/control/ComboBox.java